# Display settings issues when switching between single/dual screen configs

Tags: display, screen, configuration

Ubuntu 22.04 still doesn't deal with display settings correctly.

I use my laptop in a few differerent configurations.

Config 1:

This is my "home config". It is a dual-screen setup. Main panel is used as primary on the right, laptop internal display on the left.

Config 2:

This is the "on the road config". Single screen, therefore the laptop display is primary.

Config 3:

This is "working config". HDMI still plugged in but laptop switched to single screen mode. Same as config 2 otherwise.

When I switch from Config 1 to Config 3, laptop display becomes primary. When switching back to config 1, I want the main panel to become primary again. However this is not how things work - so right now, I have to fix the screen settings every time I go back from single screen to to dual screen. Sometimes it also decides on its own accord that my main panel has now moved to the left of the laptop. It's very annoying. Is there something I can do to make Ubuntu remember my preferred settings per configuration?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Are you using `autorandr`? If yes, paste 'working config' append on your question.

Comment: Not using autorandr, just "function" button + screen button on the laptop.

- I configure dual screen correctly

- press fn-screen combo to switch to internal display only

- then press fn-screen combo to switch back to "join displays"

- xrandr output now shows LVDS-1 has become primary instead of the HDMI-1 main panel which was previously set as my primary.

Comment: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --primary --output LVDS-1 --auto --left-of HDMI-1` I hope this command works on a new keyboard shortcut.